# Ionic cordova run error due to androidx.core:core-ktx

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic4

Last few days I'm getting errors while run Cordova build. It's showing linking resources failed. Automatically it's fetching **androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.2**, can anyone help me to update **androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0** in ionic 4.